# Security vulnerability if _vti_bin/authentication.asmx allowed for anonymous users access?

Tags: 2013, 2016

I block _vti_bin/authentication.asmx in SharePoint 2013 web application web.config file.
even when I disable anonymous access to this web service it is opened for anonymous users.
Is it any security vulnerability if it is allowed for anonymous users access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this isn't a security vulnerability. You should not be adjusting security settings via IIS or the web.config. All Web App security should only be changed via Central Administration -> Manage Web Applications or via SharePoint PowerShell.

Anonymous is enabled on the IIS site due to the implementation of Claims authentication.

For security hardening, see [Plan security hardening for SharePoint Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/sharepoint/security-for-sharepoint-server/security-hardening). If it is outside of the scope of this for SharePoint, it likely isn't a supported change.

Comment: Thanks Trevor ,Is any references that mentioned this is not vulnerability bcz we SharePoint  show any references to security team

Comment: You should open a support case with Microsoft if you need an official statement.